# 2013 Workflow Wait for Event Alternative

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

Let me start by saying I am very new to WFs. I am designing a 2013 WF in SPD 2013 and ran into a road block.
As of right now my WF gets to a step where it checks to see if we need to create a new document or modify an existing one if it exists.
The only relevant action I've come across that does along the lines of what I need it to do is the Wait for Event action. However, the only customization to that action is wait for a document add or wait for a document change in a selected library.
Let's say the WF checks and we need to create a new document, the next step is to notify a user they need to create a document then wait for document add. Say another user adds a document to the selected library, the WF will start back up won't it?
Is there a way to wait for a specific document that can be associated to the current WF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking if the document has been uploaded, could you not instead create a task to the user to upload the document.  Once they have done so they mark the task complete and the WF continues on?  This will still force the WF to wait, but requires the user who is supposed to add the document to mark their work as done.  This way you don't have to worry about another user uploading a document to affect your workflow.

The only way I can think of doing what you are doing in an SPD WF is, once the add event occurs have the WF check to see if it was that person who did it.  If not, go back to the waiting stage.  I have done something like this before, but it was against an editable field and not the adding of an attachment so I can't say how it will work.

I have done it so you can assign a task to the user and they actually attach the file to the task which in turn attaches it to the library, but this was in a SP2010 custom code workflow and not something you are looking to do.  So again, my suggestion is to make your WF task based as opposed to Wait for Event based.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here's where my ignorance to SP WFs shows, but I've only seen tasks that had Approved/Rejected options. To me it makes tasks appear to be primarily for review/approval steps. It makes sense that it should be a task, I just didn't know if I could make it to where the task didn't depend on Approve/Rejected but rather a "finished" option after they had completed the task.